# What height porch requires a railing?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, health-safety-shmira, maakeh

What are the different opinions of heights (in American or metric units) that requires a railing for the side of a porch?

Comment: Welcome to the site! As this is for you a practical question, please [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) rather than relying in practice on answers here.

Comment: Thanks! Will do. Sort of lost in the proper decorum of a SE site. But in any case, how about the first two questions?

Comment: I've edited the question so that it doesn't look like a request for personal halachic advice. It seems clear that there are two questions here and that it might make sense to split them into two separate posts.

Comment: Split. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9307/799.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-maakeh.htm

> A ma'akeh is required at the edge of any floor that people walk on, if
>   the floor is more than ten t'fachim (40 inches) above the ground or
>   above the next floor.