# Are bushes acceptable for elevations that require a maakeh, a fence?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, health-safety-shmira, maakeh

If evergreen bushes span the entire length of a side of a porch, at about waist-height for someone on the porch, do the bushes remove the need for a railing? The difference being that a railing can be relied on to prevent a fall while bushes *may* prevent a fall.

Comment: I would think yes. I was told the barrier is only needed to warn people, not to prevent. Bushes might even be better since nobody will lean on the bushes.

Comment: @avi: I'm not so sure about that. Shulchan Aruch (Choshen Mishpat 427:5) says that "it has to be strong, such that a person can lean on it and it won't fall." True that people don't usually lean on bushes, but if someone does, it won't break his fall.

Comment: it's difficult to get through most hedge bushes.  Guess it depends on the bushes and depends on the railing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-mitzvos-maakeh.htm

> The ma'akeh does not have to be a solid wall, but any spaces should be
>   sufficiently narrow that a child cannot fall through. The ma'akeh
>   should be sufficiently sturdy that it will hold back a person who
>   falls against it.